# Excel Scientific Notation to string conversion in C# programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, datatable

what i've already done...

1. reading the excel file content into datatable
2. one of column contains data in scientific notation (e.g 6.75436E+12)

   ```
       string filename = Server.MapPath("testfile.xlsx");
       string conStr = "";
       string Extension = ".xlsx";
       switch (Extension)
       {
           case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
               conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"]
                        .ConnectionString;
               break;
           case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
               conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"]
                         .ConnectionString;
               break;
       }
       conStr = String.Format(conStr, filename, "Yes");
       OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
       OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
       OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

       //Get the name of First Sheet
       connExcel.Open();
       DataTable dtExcelSchema;
       dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
       string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
       connExcel.Close();

       //Read Data from First Sheet
       connExcel.Open();
       cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
       oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
       oda.Fill(dt);
       connExcel.Close();
   ```

   how can scientific notation be converted to actual data (e.g 6754357899912)

Comment: Hey did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

`double result = Double.Parse("6.75436E+12", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);`

*NB that when you hover the value in c# it'll look like sci still but it is indeed a double.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but this doesn't give me the desired value I wanted. The output should be 6754357899912 instead of 6754360000000.0

Comment: Well, that comes down to an issue with what's being read from excel. "6.75436" only provide 5 decimal places and not the 11 you're asking for. This is actually not a c# question but an excel one. Ignoring that though here's what you want to do: Select your data, right click, and click "Format cells..." and choose `Number`. This will stop excel from presenting your data as sci and from there you shouldn't have any issues in c#

Comment: I totally agree with you on this one. The point is that the file is not to be manually tampered.

Comment: Are there any Excel helper classes where we can update the whole column to string???

Comment: If you can't tamper with the file then we have a stonewall I believe. Excel defaults to presenting large numbers as sci with up to 5 decimals of accuracy. Thus, that's the most precision we can achieve in converting them. There's absolutely no way I'm afraid to be more accurate than that without changing the format to `Number`. A possible work around for this would be to make a copy of the file you can't tamper, change the format on the copied version to `Number` and perform your script on it like so.